# How to set a variable for nested loops?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, loops

I would like to write a function which accepts as input the number of nested loops which the function will perform. For example, if the input parameter is 3, the function will perform 3 nested loops as follows :

```
for i=0:[any]
 for j=0:[any]
  for k=0:[any]
```

and if the input parameter is 2, it would be like this :

```
for i=0:[any]
 for j=0:[any]
```

How can I implement this algorithm ?

Comment: this idea can be implemented using recursion. you cannot do this by just using loops.

Comment: Is this homework? Have you tried anything?

Comment: What is the upper limit of i, j, etc? Can we assume it's the same for all such variables?

Comment: @ralph Thx. I would try recursion, but I'm not sure if it could do the same thing as well.

Comment: @JosephMansfield I'm Sorry if the question is dummy! Actually I'm not a programmer. I learn things which I need them.

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes! absolutely!

Comment: @user3480598 I wasn't suggesting your question is stupid. I was just trying to get some context so we can better help you.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Sorry for miss understanding. thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above, this problem can usually be solved by recursion.

Somehow like this:

```
function res = nestedloop_function(numLoops,remainingParams)
    res = rec_function(numLoops,[],remainingParams);
end

function res = rec_function(numLoops, loopVars, remainingParams)
    if numLoops == 0
        res = whatever(loopVars, remainingParams);
        return res;
    end

    for k = 1:[any]
        loopVars = [loopVars,k];
        res = rec_function(numLoops-1, loopVars, remainingParams);
    end
end
```

If you don't want to have the overhead of passing `remainingParams` and `loopVars` you can think about declaring them as `global`, but it is often better to avoid this...

Answer (score 2):

You can "pack" all loops into a single loop. The following code assumes that

- The upper limit of all loops is the same;
- You only want to do stuff in the innermost loop.

Matlab code:

```
N = 3; %// number of loops
M = 10; %// range for each variable is from 0 to M-1

for generalCounter = 0:M^N-1
   counters = dec2base(generalCounter,M,N)-'0';
   %// Now you are at the innermost "loop". counters(1) is your "i",
   %// counters(2) is your "j" etc
end
```

The key is to use a general counter and from that compute the counters `i`,  `j` etc. This is done in Matlab with `dec2base(...)-'0'`. The `-'0'` part is necessary because `dec2base` returns a char array, so `-'0'` converts each char to the number it represents. In other languages it may be done differently, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, but the outer loops has their functionality too!. the Functionality of all loops is same ... In other word, assume that we have 2 loops and an array. the outer loop increases one of elements and the inner loops for each element increases the element and checks for something.

Comment: With an arbitray number of loops, I don't see how you may include functionalty in each loop. Perhaps edit the answer (or post a new one) to explain what you want to do with those loops. Maybe the solution is not nested loops

Comment: That doesn't fit well in a comment. Please edit the question, or post a new one. If possible, provide a small exampl with input and the result you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single flat loop and keep track of your looping variables in an array that is treated as an odometer: Advance the loop by increasing the innermost variable, resetting and carrying over to the the next outer variable as necessary. Stop the loop when the carry would go beyond your number of nested pasudo-loops.

Here's a solution in C with an infinite flat loop that uses an auxiliary function to advance the loop variables and test for odometer overflow:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void odo_init(int ix[], int n)
{
    while (n--) ix[n] = 0;
}

int odo(int ix[], int m, int n)
{
    int i = 0;

    do {
        ix[i]++;
        if(ix[i] < m) return 1;
        ix[i++] = 0;
    } while (i < n);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int m = 2;
    int n = 4;
    int ix[n];

    odo_init(ix, n);

    do {
        int i;

        /* Do something, e.g. print loop vars */
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (i) printf(", ");
            printf("%d", ix[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        /* Advance and test loop variables */
    } while(odo(ix, m, n));

    return 0;
}
```

(The function `odo_init` is nesessary, because variable-length arrays cannot be initialised with `ix[n] = {0}`.)

---

If you don't mind the obscurity of C preprocessor macros, you could use this framework to write a `multi_for`:

```
#define multi_for(ix, m, n)                 \
    for (int ix[n], ix##_cnt_ = 0;          \
        !(ix##_cnt_ || odo_init(ix, n));    \
        ix##_cnt_++)                        \
        for (int ix##_aux_ = 1;             \
            ix##_aux_;                      \
            ix##_aux_ = odo(ix, m, n))
```

The macro is admittedly clumsy. It creates the local loop variable array `ix` and two hidden variables by token pasting. The outer `for` loop is just there to properly initialise the loop variable array. The `do` ... `while` has been rewritten as `for`, so that you can invoke the macro like a regular for loop:

```
int main()
{    
    int N = 4;

    multi_for(ix, 2, N) {
        int i;

        /* Do something, e.g. print loop vars */
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (i) printf(", ");
            printf("%d", ix[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For this to work, you must alter `odo_init` to return 0:

```
int odo_init(int ix[], int n)
{
    while (n--) ix[n] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

This macro relies on defining variables inside `for` and on variable-length arrays and thus requires C99.

Answer (score 1):

this might work for you.

there are a few assumptions though.
 1. you can execute something in the innermost loop only.
 2. all the nested loop have same upper limit

```
void loop(int n)
{
    if(n < 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    int i;
    loop(--n);
    for( i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", i); //consider this portion to be executing inside the inner most loop 
    }
    }
int main()
{
    int x;
    int n = 5; //number of for loops you wanted nested
    loop(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too difficult to implement with recursion, though it still seems an odd use-case.
Anyway, this keeps code as understandable as possible while being 'infinitely' extendable*
Each loop has it's own functionallity too (though is identical) as you have specified in comments to other answers.

```
void do_loop(std::vector<int> *loop_vars, int loop_level, int max_loop_level, int loop_iter_limit, void* data)
{
  while(loop_vars[loop_level] < loop_iter_limit)
  {
    //do work on *data
    *loop_vars[loop_level]++;
    do_loop(loop_vars, loop_level+1, max_loop_level, loop_iter_limit, data);
  }
  else
  {
    return;
  }
}

void nestedloops(int loop_count, loop_limit, void* data)
{
  std::vector<int> vars;
  for (int i = 0; i<loop_count; i++)
    vars.pushback(0);
  do_loop(&vars, 0, loop_count, loop_limit, data);
  return;
}
```

call with `nestedloops(5,10,data);` for example to do 5 nested loops with 10 iterations per loop.

You **will** want to change the `void* data` to something more appropriate (I don't know what work you will be doing).
When manipulating the data, the loop variables (`i,j,k...`) are supplied by the vector, so instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i<max; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j<max; j++)
  {
    x += i+j;
  }
}
```

you would replace the work (in this case `x=i+j`) with

```
*data += loop_vars[0]+loop_vars[1];
```

`void* data` would be changed to `int* data`

and instead of the loops, you would call

```
nestedloops(2,max,&x);
```

Please comment if you need clarification.

*not sure if the compiler will be able to perform `tail call elimination` on this, if not, you are restricted by stack depth.  However I think 500 (GCC default) is enough nested loops to start off with, and it *can* be configured higher, but again I don't know your use-case, and run time will get horriffic before this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `meshgrid` to generate all combinations.

Consider, for example, you have a vector `limits` of unknown length, where each loop should be carried out `for idx_k = 1:limit(k)`. Then

```
 function unknownNested( limts )
 n = numel(limits); %// how many neted loops there are
 range = cell(1,n); %// range for each loop
 for ii=1:n
     range(ii) = 1:limits(ii);
 end      
 [idx{1:n}] = meshgrid( range{:} );
 idx = cellfun( @(x) x(:), idx, 'uni', false ); %// "flatten" all ranges
 allRanges = [idx{:}];
 %// now you can loop once over all combinations
 for ii = 1:size(allRanes,1)
     counters = allRanges(ii,:); %// now you have an n-vector with the counter of each nested loop
     %// do you work here...
 end
```

Answer (score -2):

You've tagged your question with both Mathlab and C++. Which one do you need? This is in C++.

If I understand your question correctly (n loops with upper limit m), then you need something like:

```
void func(int countLoops, int loopUpperLimit) {

    // simpler code with 2 loops
    while (countLoops-- > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < loopUpperLimit; i++) {
            // do something
        }
    }

    // shorter code with one loop
    for (int i = 0, limit = loopUpperLimit * countLoops; i < limit; i++) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The code above assumes you don't need the individual control variables (i, j, k and so on).

Comment: The OP wants _nested_ loops

Comment: this will execute the next for loop after the previous one has been executed and finished. not giving nested loops.

Comment: Actually I would do this in Mathlab. But I thinked that I can do this with mex. so I taged matlab, C++ and C.

Comment: Thx for answering but that is not what I need.